Hoiw can I make a latex header like this?
How do I make a header like this in LaTeX?

I want it to appear on top of each page. 1(7) refers to page 1 out of 7.

Copied from comment by MS-SPO:
This is what I got so far:
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{lastpage} 
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhf{} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt} % Page number in the upper-right corner 
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage{} (\pageref{LastPage})} fancyhead[C]{ 
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{3cm}p{3cm}@{}} \textbf{Row 1, Column 1} & \textbf{Row 1, Column 2} \\
 \textbf{Row 2, Column 1} & \textbf{Row 2, Column 2} \\
 \textbf{Row 3, Column 1} & \textbf{Row 3, Column 2} \\ 
\textbf{Row 4, Column 1} & \textbf{Row 4, Column 2} \\ 
\end{tabular} }


Welcome to TeX.SX! What did you try already?

This is what I got so far:
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
% Page number in the upper-right corner
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage{} (\pageref{LastPage})}
fancyhead[C]{
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{3cm}p{3cm}@{}}
\textbf{Row 1, Column 1} & \textbf{Row 1, Column 2} \
\textbf{Row 2, Column 1} & \textbf{Row 2, Column 2} \
\textbf{Row 3, Column 1} & \textbf{Row 3, Column 2} \
\textbf{Row 4, Column 1} & \textbf{Row 4, Column 2} \
\end{tabular}
}

Please edit your question to post your code (click on the  "Edit" link). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Please don't downvote below a score of -1, even if the question in its current form needs some improvement. A score of -1 is enough to show that the question needs work, anything below that is of no use. Don't forget, it's a new user!

It's not clear to me how what you have so far is supposed to be your best attempt at the desired outcome.  Can't you at least put in "Kalle", "Unit", "Google #", etc.?

The following provides a template for your setup. Minor adjustments may be needed depending on the logo size*.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in,headheight=100pt,includeheadfoot]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\fancypagestyle{newheader}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Add header rule
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove footer rule (default)
  \fancyhead[L]{%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{} l @{}}
      \includegraphics[height=2\normalbaselineskip]{example-image} \\ % Your logo
      \bfseries Unit \\
      \tiny Author \\
      Kalle \\
      \tiny Company 2 \\
      Google 2
    \end{tabular}}
  \fancyhead[R]{%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{} l r @{}}
      TYPE & \thepage~(\pageref{LastPage}) \\
      \begin{tabular}{@{} l l l @{}}
        \tiny Date & \tiny Issue & \tiny Document ID \\
        2024-05-14 & 1           & 123
      \end{tabular} \\
      \tiny Company 1 \\
      Google 1 \\
      \tiny Company 3 \\
      Google 3
    \end{tabular}}
}

%\setlength{\headheight}{100pt}% If you're not using geometry
\pagestyle{newheader}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-55]

\end{document}

* You could use \rule{0pt}{2\normalbaselineskip}\smash{\includegraphics[<options>]{<logo>}} to include the logo with whatever <options> yet still have it only take up "2 rows" in the tabular.

Thank you so much! I always have trouble getting alignments correct etc. But this is great!

The following is NOT an answer, but it's at least compileable. It may help you get started with others' input. Also, many of us will assume that you are providing the "Google" logo as a graphic.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{lastpage} 
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhf{} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt} % Page number in the upper-right corner 

\begin{document}

\fancyhead[L]{\fbox{Logo Here}}

\fancyhead[R]{\thepage{} (\pageref{LastPage})} 

\fancyhead[C]{
    \raggedleft
    \begin{tabular}{@{}p{3cm}p{3cm}@{}}
        \textbf{Row 1, Column 1} & \textbf{Row 1, Column 2} \\
        \textbf{Row 2, Column 1} & \textbf{Row 2, Column 2} \\
        \textbf{Row 3, Column 1} & \textbf{Row 3, Column 2} \\ 
        \textbf{Row 4, Column 1} & \textbf{Row 4, Column 2} \\ 
\end{tabular} }

\end{document}

I'm not sure that I would use a tabular for this problem . . .?
